# Proving a subgroup of the symmetric group $(S_z, ∘)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$S_z = \{F: Z → Z : F $ *is a bijection onto*$\ Z\}$. $(S_z, ∘)$ is a group.

**Question**

Let $H = \{F ∈ S_z : $ *for each n*$\ ∈ Z_+, F(n) ∈ Z_+\}$. Is $H$ a subgroup of $(S_z, ∘)$?

**My Proof:**

$H ≠ ∅$ as the identity function $i ∈ S_z ∈ H$, since $i(n) = n$ for all $n ∈ F(n)$.

Let $f, g ∈ H$, then $f ∘ g(n) = f(g(n)) = f(n) = n$.

If $f ∈ S_z$, then $f^{-1}(n) = f^{-1} (f(n)) = i(n) = n$, since $f(n) = n$. Therefore, $f^{-1} ∈ H$.

Since we have proven the identity function exists, closure, and the inverse function exists, H is a subgroup.

---

I feel like I have a huge misunderstanding on what the set H is. In my mind it's $\{1, 2, ..., n\} → \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\} $ where$\ n ∈ Z_+$.

(I'm not very good at solving these problems)

Comment: "$f(g(n)) = f(n) = n$" - this isn't true in general. Both $g(n)$ and $f(g(n))$ will usually be different from $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a subgroup, every element should have an inverse. The problem here is that there are bijections from Z to Z which send Z+ into Z+ but that don't have similar inverses.  For example, send every number x to x+1.  This is a bijection and all the positives go to positives,  but you can't send 1 back to 0 and stay in the positives.  So no... it's not a subgroup.

Comment: On review, quasi beat me to this answer!

Comment: But you explained it nicely, and in more detail, so it's good (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $f(n)=n+1$, for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $f\in H$,  but $f^{-1}\notin H$, hence $H$ is not a subgroup of $S_{\mathbb{Z}}$.